# Access form data from userFunc of userType element

Tags: typo3, flexform

I would like to access the whole data of the whole Element inside my userFunc.

I tinkered around by var_dumping the secondArgument (fObj) of the userFunc and found it deep inside nested but I don't know if there is maybe an easier way to access it.

I would like to create a list of checkboxes depending on data from an another sheet inside the flexform.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to access your method parameters?

```
public function bla($content, $conf) {}
```

additionally try to enter the cObj:

```
$test = $this->cObj;
$data = $test->getData();
```

Comment: my userFunc doesn't extend from anything so $this is NULL.
I followed this example:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/7.6/en-us/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html#example